# It happened the same to me as John

Tags: grammar

Let us suppose something happened first to John and then to me. Is it grammatically correct to say:

> It happened the same to me as John.

And if it is not, how would express this meaning, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same happened to me as happened to John.

The same happened to me as to John.

The same thing happened to me as it did to John.

Comment: Or another (I think): "The same as happened to John, happened to me"

Comment: Note: the original phrasing is grammatically wrong, but you will hear that construction in speech from time to time, simply because we do not always speak grammatically perfect at all times.

Answer (score 6):

It would need to be:

> It happened the same to me as **to** John.

You need to repeat the "to". In order to make it easier to read though, I would add another couple of words:

> It happened the same to me as **it did to** John.

Comment: Why does it need to be this way? That is, what makes the asker's original sentence grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not grammatically correct. To express that, you'd say *"what happened to John also happened to me"* or simply *"what happened to John happened to me ..."*

Comment: What makes it grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Because it is parsed is "[It happened] [the same] [to me] as [to John]", not "[It happened] [the same] to [me as John]." Note the difference between "as" and "and" - both of the following are correct: "[It happened] [the same] to [me and John]" and "It happened the same [to me] and [to John]". The phrase "me as John" could mean something like "me pretending to be John" or "me acting the part of John in a play or a film" but that doesn't make sense in your original sentence.

Comment: @alephzero - great explanation, do you mind if I edit that into my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would say: The same thing that happened to John happened to me, too.